# setDrawingOptions after baselayer change Leaflet Draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm trying to change the color for my polygon after I change the baselayer. I've used `setDrawingOptions` but it is not working...

When I log the object before and after the `setDrawingOptions` it changes. But I don't see the change on the already drawn polygon's. 
When I draw a new polygon, it draw's with the new color.

I'm using Leaflet 0.7.x

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function(){
  map.drawControl.setDrawingOptions({
    polygon: {
      shapeOptions: {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The event is triggered. And there are no console errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that drawControl is created like:

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw();
```

If yes, then it is not a property of the map object and in your console you should have an error like:

```
"map.drawControl is undefined"
```

Please, try the following code (I only removed the "map." part before "drawControl")

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function(){
  drawControl.setDrawingOptions({
    polygon: {
      shapeOptions: {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Now that you edited your post, it is clear. You want the already drawn polygons to change color, too. The polygons you create are hosted in a layerGroup or featureGroup, let's call it "drawnItems". So what you have to do is simply:

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function(){
  drawControl.setDrawingOptions({
    polygon: {
      shapeOptions: {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    }
  });

  drawnItems.setStyle({
    color:"#fff"
  })
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jt7wy4eg/2/
Changes are applied when user zooms in/out (polygons become red, even the drawn ones).

Comment: drawControl is created like this: ` map.drawControl = new L.Control.Draw()`. And there are no console errors